# Что делать с переопределением макросов?

Tags: c, header, макросы

В одном из заголовочных файлов присутствует определение макроса

```
#define ERROR( ... ) log_message( NULL, EMIT_ERR, MODULE_NAME, __VA_ARGS__ )
```

Включив `windows.h` я переопределил это определение следующим:

```
#define ERROR 0
```

Соответственно, при компиляции я получаю ошибки вида:

```
called object is not a function or function pointer
ERROR( error );
^
```

Я понимаю, что могу это решить, переименовав макрос и заменив во всех файлах его имя 1 нажатием кнопки, но меня интересует, существует ли более лаконичный путь решения.

Я уже пробовал менять порядок включения (ставить `windows.h` перед заголовочным файлом, в котором присутствует определение). Пробовал вставлять следующую конструкцию перед определением:

```
#ifdef ERROR 
#undef ERROR
#endif
```

Но ошибка всё ещё присутствует.

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы оно работало(log_message..)? Тогда переименовывайте, и не используйте больше таких простых имён. `PASAf_ERROR` подойдёт)

Comment: `define error` и `define error(...)` не одно и то же...

Comment: Чего именно (маленький примерчик кода только приведите) вы хотите добиться? Переименовать макрос в .c перед трансляцией?

Comment: @avp, я хочу сохранить функционал обеих в пределах тех областей, где они используются и избежать ошибок при компиляции.

Comment: Ловите макросы `M` и `M(x)` в ответе

Comment: Так а у вас в вашем коде используется определение `ERROR` из `windows.h`? Я вижу в виндушных хедерах единственный макрос, зависящий от их определения `ERROR` - это `RGN_ERROR`. Т.е. неявно протащить `ERROR` к себе в код вы можете только через `RGN_ERROR`. Есть у вас в коде использование виндушных `ERROR` и `RGN_ERROR`?

Comment: @AnT, у меня в коде - нет. Но я не ручаюсь за подключенные GL, GTK.

Comment: В принципе, меня бы удовлетворил ответ "Лаконичного пути решения - нет." Я не сведущь во всех тонкостях и хакерских решениях, просто предположил, что существует решение, которое позволит мне не редактировать `windows.h` и/или не переименовывать макрос (который уже использован в >200 местах в 10 разных файлах).

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что это вообще правильный подход
(возможно лучшим решением будет просто отредактировать файлы, правильно изменив имена макросов),
но в принципе, подобную штуку можно изобразить примерно так:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat tmac1.h
#undef M
#define M(x) puts("tmac1 M: "#x)
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat tmac2.h
#undef M
#define M puts("tmac2 M")
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat tmac.c
#include <stdio.h>

#include "tmac2.h"

int main () {
  M;
#include "tmac1.h"
  M(xoxo xxa);
  M(123);
#include "tmac2.h"
  M;
#include "tmac1.h"
  M(End);
}
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc tmac.c && ./a.out 
tmac2 M
tmac1 M: xoxo xxa
tmac1 M: 123
tmac2 M
tmac1 M: End
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Т.е. макросы раскидываются по разным .h файлам, каждый из которых подгружается в нужном месте кода.

**Update 1** (вот, пришло в голову, что препроцессор можно и 2 раза использовать)

Несколько усложнив компиляцию, конечно, можно и приукрасить код, отказавшись от `#include` в точках переключения между макросами (заменяем директиву `#include` на макрос переключения).

Например, вот так:

```
#define USE1 \
  #undef M \
  #define M(x) puts("tmac1 M: "#x)

#define USE2 \
  #undef M \
  #define M puts("tmac2 M")

int main () {
  USE2
  M;
  USE1
  M(xoxo xxa);
  M(123);
  USE2
  M;
  USE1
  M(End);
}
```

И тогда:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc -E tmac.c | sed 's/#define/\n#define/' | gcc -o tmac1 -x c -
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./tmac1
tmac2 M
tmac1 M: xoxo xxa
tmac1 M: 123
tmac2 M
tmac1 M: End
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Работает, как и в первом варианте, дополнительные .h файлы не нужны.

Comment: Что ж, это решение... но оно не избавляет меня от необходимости вставить во всех файлах, где используется вторая версия макроса USE2 (что равносильно включению определения, и требует точно такого же количества нажатия клавиш)

Comment: А вы что хотели? Попробуйте объяснить попонятней (и с примерами вашего кода)

Comment: Иначе не понятно, почему тривиальные `#undef ERROR` и потом `#define ERROR log_message(...)` в вашем файле, включенным последним не работает.

Comment: Eсли бы мне было понятно - я бы сюда не шёл.

Answer (score 1):

Если вашему коду нужно именно ваше определение `ERROR`, то  просто обеспечьте тот порядок включения заголовочных файлов, при котроом ваше определение макро всегда включется в единицы трансляции после `windows.h`. По идее, так оно само собой и должно получиться, если вы придерживаетесь практики включать системные заголовочные файлы в первую очередь, а свои собственные - только после них.

Перед вашим определением макро, разумеется, не забудьте сделать

```
#ifdef ERROR 
#undef ERROR
#endif
```

При этом вы, понятное дело, потеряете доступ к виндушному определению `ERROR`, также к определенному через него `RGN_ERROR` (вроде больше зависимостей нет).

Comment: Я так и сделал, но почему-то ошибка всё ещё присутствует.